# How do I get to the Nuka World transit?

Tags: fallout-4

I am attempting to enter Nuka World, but every entrance to the transit is considered out of the map, and there is an invisible barrier. How do I get into Nuka World?

Comment: Maybe uninstall the DLC and reinstall it?

Comment: i turned off my xbox earlier, ill see if it works tomorrow. While i cut off the game and restarted it i never shut down my xbox, so that may be a potential reason.

Comment: I've heard of other people encountering the invisible barrier. It's a bug.

Comment: does it have a fix?

Comment: @Sparta270 Not that I know of. I just saw it mentioned a lot in the comments section of a Nuka-World BethSoft Instagram post.

Answer (score 7):

I entered Nuka World last night. The [Nuka-World Transit Center](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Nuka-World_transit_center) is way to the west edge of the map.

[image: Nuka World Transit Center Location]

I fast traveled to the [Lonely Chapel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lonely_Chapel) to its northeast, and just walked right up to it. There's a highway that leads into the main entrance.

I didn't want to enter the main entrance, since there were enemies there and I was using a stealth character, but I found a gap in the fence to the north of the main entrance.

Here's a video on YouTube of someone approaching the transit center from the [Sunshine Tidings Co-Op](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sunshine_Tidings_co-op). The transit center comes into view around 4:40.

Comment: I have tried coming to the transit center from almost every direction including the overpass, and it simply wont let me enter, is says that it is out of the map.

Comment: @Sparta270 So you're walking up to the gateway shown in the video still, and there's an invisible barrier across it?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but I discovered if I deleted the regrowth overhaul mod I was able to walk right through

Answer (score -3):

Hey guys have you tried to "fly" there with a brotherhood ship.
Im trying to see if that works if it does ill notify you guys.

Comment: Welp flying wont work. buttt you can fast travel to the cave outside of the map and head to the place

Answer (score -5):

I've figured out a way! Go through the dark green barriers on the map it will let u through!

Comment: What dark green barriers?  I don't remember any dark green barriers being there.